Interesting solutions of equation x^y = y^x
There is simple equation $x^y=y^x$. By taking logarithm we can see that it is equivalent to $\frac{\ln x}{x}=\frac{\ln y}{y}$. When we plot and inspect the function $f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$, we can see that for every $x\in(1,e)\cup(e,+\infty)$ there exist two solutions. First is trivial $x=y$. Second non-trivial can be expressed as $y=-\frac{x W(-\frac{\ln x}{x})}{\ln x}$.
Still, from the school mathematics we know that this equation has one simple non-trivial solution: $x=2, y=4$.
Question. Is it a coincidence? Are there some other "interesting" non-trivial solutions: two rational, two algebraic or so? Or this non-trivial pair is the only "interesting"?

For any value of $x$ there are at most two $y$ solutions, so it would appear you have found all of them in your first paragraph.

It is a well-known result, usually discussed in high school olympiad training camps, that the equation $x^y=y^x$ has two nontrivial solutions in positive integers: $(2,4)$ and $(4,2)$. The proof relies on what you also observed: the function $x\mapsto x^{1/x}$ is strictly decreasing for $x>e$. Note that this site is for research level questions. For general questions in mathematics see http://math.stackexchange.com/, but study this guide first before asking any question there: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/

Let $x = (\frac{s+1}{s})^s$ and $y = (\frac{s+1}{s})^{s+1}$.

There are many algebraic solutions like $x=\frac 94,,y=\frac{27}8$ and $x=\sqrt 3,,y=3\sqrt 3$. All the rational solutions have been determined in this paper. A description of all algebraic solutions appears to be unknown.
